# Creating JFrame in a new Thread(new messageloog)

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

Hi 
i am trying to create multi JFrames but I want each one to has its own Thread (message loop) ,so when one JFrame freezes the others will keep working

i tried to create each jframe from different Threads, but they are still working in the "AWT-EventQueue-0" thread.

i come from a dotnet background. so when i want to do this scenario in a winForms app i usually call

`Application.run(new form())`

from  a new thread

can u please tell me how to do this in java ?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

There is only UI thread in Java, no matter how many frames you open. I would suggest you to execute the long running operation within a thread.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    new Thread(new FrameRunnable()).start();
}

public class FrameRunnable implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
        // Do stuff here
    }
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: thanks, i guess this is the only work around.but i am kinda surprised that such feature doesn't exist in java:(

Answer (score 1):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) to understand how the Event Dispatch Thread works. All updates to GUI components must be done on the EDT. If you have long running tasks, you can use a SwingWorker or a separate Thread along with SwingUtilities.invoke(...) later to add code to the EDT.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new thread for each JFrame generated. Take note of your Thread variables and pass it around on your Runnable.

Comment: I've tried it and it doesn't work . i still have only one message loop "AWT-EventQueue-0".therefore when one JFrame freezes the others freeze to